# Delphi show progress on clientdataset open

Tags: delphi, progress-bar

My current code

```
   Screen.Cursor := crSQLWait;
   ProgressDlg := TProgressDlg.Create(Application);
   try
      ProgressDlg.ProgressLabel.Caption := 'Loading data. Please wait...';
      ProgressDlg.Show;
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      if MainCDS.RemoteServer <> nil then
      begin
         MainCDS.Active := false;
         MainCDS.Active := true; 
      end;
   finally
      FreeAndNil(ProgressDlg);
      Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
   end;
```

How can I make my marquee progressbar on ProgressDlg move while MainCDS is opening, cause now progressbar is freezed while MainsCDS is opening. Hope You understand my problem.

Comment: Have you tried a `TThreadTimer` like `TJvThreadTimer` to update the ProgressDlg while the data is being pulled?  We pull data from a DataSnap server (we don't use `.RemoteServer`) and using the `TJvThreadTimer` works to update the progress bar if we also retrieve the data on a separate thread.

Comment: Now, I haven't tried threading.

Comment: Keeping the UI responsive is only part of the problem I assume. Actually updating the progressbar (let it grow) according to the load process requires some kind of progress event on the server as well.

Comment: @NGLN Not really. It's a marquee progress bar. It just shuffles back and forth. That's usually enough to stop the user getting too paranoid.

Comment: @David: on Vista+ and with no bounds and state set.
On XP- or if bar is liek 1-to-100 then it is not shuffling. He's to use CDS events

Comment: @Arioch'The The question says "my marquee progress bar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the database access and the progress dialog in different threads. That's the only option because the databse access code is synchronous with no callbacks. Well, I'm assuming that your database layer does not offer regular callbacks that you could use to keep the UI alive. Is that so?

If you cannot put the database code in a background thread, then you are in a bind. The GUI code for the progress dialog wants to be in the main thread. If you move that to a background thread then you can't use the VCL since it is tied to the main GUI thread. So you may need to resort to raw Win32 API calls.

Comment: I think it does not offer any callbacks. Can You show some example how to run thoses processes in different threads, cause I haven't used threads and I can't find any usefull example.

Comment: There are plenty of useful examples of threading out there. Search harder. The Delphi examples contain threading examples.

Comment: What is MainCDS type ? few quotes from Delphi help: "AfterGetRecords event - Occurs after the client dataset fetches a data packet from the provider. " and "OnGetData event - Occurs after a provider retrieves data but before it is sent to the client."

Comment: @Arioch'The I don't see how that is relevant. The time delay here is on initial connection.

Comment: OmniThreadLibrary have a lot of examples, AsyncCalls Lib docs are just example...

Comment: @David if CDS is bound to some db-aware grid it would instantly start fetching at least some data, or like default mode of cxGrid - the whole table.